# Get value of HTML element within PHP on same page?

Tags: php, html

In the past, whenever I needed to get the value of an html element, I would always submit a form to load a different page. Something like:

page1.php

```
<form name="form1" action="page2.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="input1" value="value1" />
</form>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
   $data = $_POST['input1'];
?>
```

My question is, is it possible to get the value of 'input1' on the same page (page1.php) without requiring clicking a submit button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **jQuery**:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['data'])) { 
        $data = $_POST['data']; 
        print( "data is: $data" ); 
        return; 
    } 
?> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 

<div>Response from server: <span id="response"></span></div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $.post('test.php',{'data': "value1"}, function (data) {
        $('#response').text(data);
    }); 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Non-jQuery** IE doesn't have the XMLHttpRequest object so here is a shim for IE:

```
Yes, using ajax / javascript:

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("input1", "value1");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "page1.php");
xhr.send(formData);

if (typeof XMLHttpRequest == "undefined") XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
    }
    catch (e) {}
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    }
    catch (e) {}
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e) {}
    //Microsoft.XMLHTTP points to Msxml2.XMLHTTP and is redundant
    throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
};
```

Comment: I like the jQuery solution, but I'm a little confused. Is that one line of code the only one needed? And where exactly does it go? How is the php variable assigned?

Comment: Yes, with jQuery you only need that one line. In your php, you would access it like $_POST['input1']

Comment: Hmmm, I must be doing something wrong. In the head of page1.php I have `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>` Then in the body I have `<form method="post" action="" name="form2">\n<input type="hidden" name="timezone" value="hi" />\n</form>\n<script type="text/javascript">$.post('page1.php', {input1: 'value1'});\n</script>\n<?php\n$data = $_POST['input1'];\nprint( "value is: $data" );\n?>` I'm getting a blank ($data is empty).

Comment: 'timezone' and 'hi' are supposed to be 'input1' and 'value1'

Comment: Man, I just can't get it to work. I've simplified it as much as possible. Here's the entire page. `<!DOCTYPE...>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $.post('test.php',{'data': "value1"});
   </script>
 <?php
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    print( "data is: $data" );
 ?>
</body>
</html>` If you need to, I can tell you the url where it's hosted.

Comment: I've added an edit with a success handler, see if it's pops up an alert with ('data is: value1')

Comment: An alert pops up that shows the entire source of the page. And yes, data is: value1 appears. But if I view the actual page source, it shows 'data is:       '.

Comment: Nothing gets printed. The $_POST array seems to be empty.

Comment: Are you doing `if(count($_POST) > 0)` not less than zero?

Comment: Yes, I just copied and pasted. Can I message you somehow? It would be easier if you could see it, but I don't want to post my URL on here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3463/discussion-between-user617123-and-iabstractdownvotefactory)

Answer (score 2):

What for? Do you want to submit it to another file without needing to actually "submit" the form?

You use JavaScript for that.

```
document.form1.input1.value
```

Comment: I wish those who vote down explain why they voted down. It's not healthy you know, voting down without any reason. =)

Comment: I think they voted you down, beacuse they expected you to bring an PHP'ish way.